# Android-emulator boot stuck in “QEMU Pipe Device:rw, wait_event error”

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I am trying to compile goldfish android kernel and run it with emulator. I did everything as the Google told me.(Android kernel compile and test with Android Emulator, How to compile android goldfish 3.4 kernel and run on emulator)。
    yesterday，I follow the tips, and lunch the android-emulator successfully. But today when I launch the emulator again, it does not work. the boot log shows it stuck in "QEMU Pipe Device:rw, wait_event error", who can help me ? thanks in advance sincerely.

environment： VMware10， ubuntu14.04，goldfish3.4，ASOP_arm，Android4.4

the part of boot log:

```
Freeing init memory: 148K
type=1403 audit(1445259070.600:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
SELinux: Loaded policy from /sepolicy
type=1404 audit(1445259070.620:3): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
init (1): /proc/1/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1/oom_score_adj instead.
init: /dev/hw_random not found
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
EXT4-fs (mtdblock0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: barrier=1
EXT4-fs (mtdblock1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
fs_mgr: Running /system/bin/e2fsck on /dev/block/mtdblock1
e2fsck: executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
e2fsck: e2fsck terminated by exit(255)
EXT4-fs (mtdblock1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
fs_mgr: Cannot mount filesystem on /dev/block/mtdblock1 at /data
init: fs_mgr_mount_all returned an error
init: /dev/hw_random not found
init: Unable to open persistent property directory /data/property errno: 2
type=1400 audit(1445259074.030:4): avc:  denied  { entrypoint } for  pid=36 comm="init" path="/sbin/healthd" dev="rootfs" ino=1232 scontext=u:r:healthd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=file
healthd: wakealarm_init: timerfd_create failed
healthd: BatteryVoltagePath not found
healthd: BatteryTemperaturePath not found
binder: 36:36 transaction failed 29189, size 0-0
init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
type=1405 audit(1445259074.370:5): bool=in_qemu val=1 old_val=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=2)
init: property 'sys.powerctl' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.powerctl}'
init: powerctl: cannot expand '${sys.powerctl}'
init: property 'sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}'
init: cannot expand '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}' while writing to '/proc/sys/vm/extra_free_kbytes'
type=1400 audit(1445259075.370:6): avc:  denied  { 0x10 } for  pid=36 comm="healthd" capability=36  scontext=u:r:healthd:s0 tcontext=u:r:healthd:s0 tclass=capability2
eth0: link up
warning: `rild' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
shell@generic:/ $ QEMU Pipe Device:rw, wait_event error
QEMU Pipe Device:rw, wait_event error
QEMU Pipe Device:rw, wait_event error
QEMU Pipe Device:rw, wait_event error
QEMU Pipe Device:rw, wait_event error
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. the reason of this error is because of the switch parameter of android-emulator. so if you do like this:

```
root@virtual-machine:/work/android4.4/out/target/product/generic# mv userdata.img userdata.img.bak
```

and then restart the emulator, emulator can not use that the userdata.img.
all because of the userdata.img. the detail of this I do not know. maybe someone will tell us in future.